# create new columns from comparing rows

Tags: pandas

My input data  is like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4], 'B':['x','y','x','y'], 'C':['S1','S1','S2','S2']})

    A   B   C
0   1   x   S1
1   2   y   S1
2   3   x   S2
3   4   y   S2
```

I want to groupby 'C'. Then for the 2 rows in group, use value of B to assign value of A into another column and reduce it to one row.

it should become

```
    C   D_x D_y
0   S1  1   2
1   S2  3   4
```

The real data has more than hundred thousand rows, but will grouped into 2 rows always. There will be other columns but they remain same within the group.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

What you need is more like a `pivot`

```
df.pivot('C','B','A')
Out[209]: 
B   x  y
C       
S1  1  2
S2  3  4
```

Comment: Thanks Wen, I ended up implementing it as pivot_table.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use `set_index`, `unstack` and column renaming and flattening:

```
dfout = df.set_index(['C','B']).unstack().rename(columns={'A':'D'})
#Python 3.6.0+
dfout.columns = [f'{i}_{j}' for i,j in dfout.columns]
#or
#dfout.columns = dfout.columns.map('_'.join)
print(dfout.reset_index())
```

Output:

```
    C  D_x  D_y
0  S1    1    2
1  S2    3    4
```